# Nesting AJAX and user events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a mini project where I need to do an ajax call against a relatively slow server, take user input, and then process the ajax response with the user input.

Because it takes a while for the AJAX call to complete, I began the call as soon as the document loaded.  In theory, it should be done by the time the user is done with their input.

This is kind of how I have it setup at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $.ajax({
        . . .
    });

    $('#btn').click(process(table));
};

function process(jqXHR) {
    //code not dependent on AJAX call

    var table = jqXHR.done(function(data) {
        return data;
    });

    //code that is dependent on AJAX call
}
```

The idea is that I keep the AJAX call asynchronous, but at a certain point I need it to be complete before I can fire off the rest of my code.  I thought that `jqXHR.done()` nested under an `onClick()` event might be what I'm looking for, but it looks like `jqXHR.done()` fires regardless of where I put the handler.

So, is there a way to to keep everything running asynchronously up until a certain point, then wait until the AJAX call is finished to continue executing a block of code?

--edit--

I have considered trying to somehow implement callbacks to do it, but honestly I have no idea how to link callbacks from 2 different co-dependent event handlers.  The co-dependent nature of it is what is really confusing me.

Comment: Do you know that `table` is a reference to the `jqXHR` object, it doesn't refer to the retuned data of the `done`'s callback. Also jQuery doesn't have `onClick` method, actually there are many things that should be fixed in here.

Comment: Yes, I know `table` is a reference to the `jqXHR` object.  I passed the object instead of the response because the response usually doesn't exist yet.  That way, after some time in `process()` I can return the response to a local variable.  I didn't directly copy and paste the code to prevent eye-bleeding, which is why I accidentally wrote `onClick()` instead of `click`.  I started learning JS literally 5 days ago, so I'm sure some of what I write won't make entirely perfect sense.

Comment: I suppose @undefined talked about `var table = jqXHR.done()`. If you think that in local variable `table` will be `data`, then you are wrong

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems to be working as long as the AJAX has completed before I start accessing `table` in `process()`.  `alert(table[0])` hasn't failed for me yet (as long as the call is done).  Scratch that, doing `alert(data[0])` under the `table = jqXHR` declaration works, but doing `alert(table[0])` after isn't. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though @undefined has already mentioned the idea and what to do, I put there full example:

```
var requestFinished = false, clicked = false;
var gotData;

$(document).on("click", '#btn', processClick);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/"
    }).done(function(data) {
        gotData = data;
        if (clicked) {
           processAll();
        } else {
            requestFinished = true;
        }
    });
});

function processClick() {
    //code not dependent on AJAX call
    if (requestFinished) {
        processAll();
    } else {
        clicked = true;
    }
}

function processAll() {
    alert(gotData.substring(0, 21));
    //code that is dependent on AJAX call
}
```

And the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gm6T/).

And another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gm6T/1/) just to test ajax delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag which indicates whether data is loaded or not, if the user clicks on the element and the response is not returned yet, you can inform the user that he/she should wait until an operation is complete.

```
// untested
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
   // . . .
})
, isDone = false
, isClicked = false;


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
       isClicked = true;
       if ( isDone === false ) {
         // show/tell something to the user
       }
       jqXHR.done(function(data) {
          isDone = true;
          if (isClicked) process(data);
       });
    });
};

function process(data) {
    //code that is dependent on AJAX call
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that puts me in the right direction :) .